# Error deploying TensorFlow App with AppEngine GoogleCloud

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed correctly the python3 App building-an-app:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard_python37/building-an-app/building-an-app-1

But now I have tried to deploy my App that use a neuronal network, and it works correctly in local with virtualenv and using requeriments.txt file:

```
Flask==1.1.1
numpy==1.17.4
scipy==1.3.2
gensim==3.8.1
tensorflow==2.0.0
```

But when I use "gcloud app deploy", after 5 minutes with this message "Updating service [default]...", I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build e281a017-86ee-450f-8291-bac8a7a0df30 status: FAILURE.
Build error details: {"error":{"errorType":"BuildError","canonicalCode":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","errorId":"3883CE8A","errorMessage":"02 Dec 2019 22:12:03 INFO     Arguments: ['--parser_script=/usr/local/bin/ftl.par', '--src=', '--entrypoint=', '--name=eu.gcr.io/lullaai-chatbot/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:8f040a55-3198-4998-beb0-75817f57192c', '--directory=/workspace', '--destination=/srv', '--cache-repository=eu.gcr.io/lullaai-chatbot/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d', '--cache', '--builder-output-path=\"\"', '--additional-directory=/.googleconfig', '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7', '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip', '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG', '--base=eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20191019_3_7_4_RC00']\n02 Dec 2019 22:12:03 INFO     Unparsed arguments: ['--name=eu.gcr.io/lullaai-chatbot/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:8f040a55-3198-4998-beb0-75817f57192c', '--directory=/workspace', '--destination=/srv', '--cache-repository=eu.gcr.io/lullaai-chatbot/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d', '--cache', '--builder-output-path=\"\"', '--additional-directory=/.googleconfig', '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7', '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip', '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG', '--base=eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20191019_3_7_4_RC00']\n02 Dec 2019 22:12:03 INFO     Executing ['/usr/local/bin/ftl.par', '--name=eu.gcr.io/lullaai-chatbot/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:8f040a55-3198-4998-beb0-75817f57192c', '--directory=/workspace', '--destination=/srv', '--cache-repository=eu.gcr.io/lullaai-chatbot/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d', '--cache', '--builder-output-path=\"\"', '--additional-directory=/.googleconfig', '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7', '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip', '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG', '--base=eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20191019_3_7_4_RC00']\nINFO     FTL version python-v0.17.0\nINFO     Beginning FTL build for python\nINFO     FTL arg passed: virtualenv_dir /env\nINFO     FTL arg passed: ttl 168\nINFO     FTL arg passed: python_cmd /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache True\nINFO     FTL arg passed: virtualenv_cmd virtualenv\nINFO     FTL arg passed: entrypoint None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: exposed_ports None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: pip_cmd /env/bin/python3.7 -m pip\nINFO     FTL arg passed: tar_base_image_path None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: export_cache_stats False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: builder_output_path \"\"\nINFO     FTL arg passed: destination_path /srv\nINFO     FTL arg passed: sh_c_prefix False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: base eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20191019_3_7_4_RC00\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache_key_version v0.17.0\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache_salt \nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache_repository eu.gcr.io/lullaai-chatbot/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d\nINFO     FTL arg passed: venv_cmd /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env\nINFO     FTL arg passed: name eu.gcr.io/lullaai-chatbot/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:8f040a55-3198-4998-beb0-75817f57192c\nINFO     FTL arg passed: global_cache False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: upload True\nINFO     FTL arg passed: fail_on_error True\nINFO     FTL arg passed: output_path None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: directory /workspace\nINFO     FTL arg passed: additional_directory /.googleconfig\nINFO     FTL arg passed: verbosity DEBUG\nINFO     starting: full build\nINFO     starting: builder initialization\nINFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20191019_3_7_4_RC00'\nINFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'eu.gcr.io/lullaai-chatbot/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:8f040a55-3198-4998-beb0-75817f57192c'\nINFO     builder initialization took 0 seconds\nINFO     starting: build process for FTL image\nINFO     starting: checking_cached_interpreter_layer\nINFO     starting: check python version\nINFO     python version full cmd:\n/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 --version\nINFO     python version stderr:\n\nINFO
```

Anybody know what could be the problem?

Checking the build log for errors, I have discovered one line that says:

`Step #1 - "builder": exited with error [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory`

So I have changed app.yaml to:

```
runtime: python37

handlers:
  # This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
  # directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

  # This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
  # required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
  # the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto

resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 8
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

But I am still getting the same error :(

It is the build log:

```
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37_app_builder:python37_20191019_3_7_4_RC00" failed: exit status 1
ERROR
Finished Step #1 - "builder"
Step #1 - "builder": IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '""/output'
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/ftl_error.py", line 77, in InternalErrorHandler
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 60, in main
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
Step #1 - "builder":     exec code in run_globals
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
Step #1 - "builder":     "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
Step #1 - "builder": Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1 - "builder": tar_runtime_package is likely not on the path
Step #1 - "builder": exited with error [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR    tar_runtime_package tar -pcf /tmp/tmplWd4v8.tar --hard-dereference --transform flags=r;s,^,/.googleconfig/, --exclude *.pyc .
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     full build took 79 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     build process for FTL image took 79 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     Building app layer took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     tar_runtime_package took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     tar_runtime_package tar -pcf /tmp/tmplWd4v8.tar --hard-dereference --transform flags=r;s,^,/.googleconfig/, --exclude *.pyc .
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: tar_runtime_package
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: Building app layer
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     Building app layer took 76 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     Finished gzipping tarfile.
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     gzip_tar_runtime_package took 58 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `gzip_tar_runtime_package` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     gzip_tar_runtime_package gzip /tmp/tmpStZGpR.tar -1
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: gzip_tar_runtime_package
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     tar_runtime_package took 8 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `tar_runtime_package` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     tar_runtime_package tar -pcf /tmp/tmpStZGpR.tar --hard-dereference --transform flags=r;s,^,/srv/, --exclude *.pyc .
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: tar_runtime_package
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: Building app layer
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     checking_cached_requirements.txt_layer took 1 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     [CACHE][HIT] v0.17.0:PYTHON (requirements)->62b99263456c1af3bff1307a585449789858bb17c695a2accfa55a3e5ee8f950
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     check python version took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `python version` stderr:
Step #1 - "builder": /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 --version
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `python version` full cmd:
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: check python version
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": gunicorn
Step #1 - "builder": tensorflow==2.0.0
Step #1 - "builder": gensim==3.8.1
Step #1 - "builder": scipy==1.3.2
Step #1 - "builder": numpy==1.17.4
Step #1 - "builder": Flask==1.1.1
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     new_descriptor_contents: 
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": gunicorn
Step #1 - "builder": tensorflow==2.0.0
Step #1 - "builder": gensim==3.8.1
Step #1 - "builder": scipy==1.3.2
Step #1 - "builder": numpy==1.17.4
Step #1 - "builder": Flask==1.1.1
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     descriptor_contents:
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     {"architecture": "amd64", "author": "Unknown", "config": {}, "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "history": [{"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Unknown", "created": "2019-12-02T22:00:00Z", "created_by": "//containerregistry/client:ftl.par"}, {"author": "Bazel", "created": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z", "created_by": "bazel build ..."}], "os": "linux", "rootfs": {"diff_ids":
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID\_ARGUMENT: unable to resolve source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56008835/error-gcloud-app-deploy-invalid-argument-unable-to-resolve-source)

Comment: Can you include output with the `--verbosity=debug` flag?

Comment: I have checked build log, and the problem looks to be related with memory 
```Step #1 - "builder": exited with error [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the feedback, I finally got it working. I had to change the app.yaml to manual scaling and env flex:

```
runtime: python37
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 8
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

and I had to create a docker image, and push it to repository, then use this image for deploy. It is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python

COPY ["main.py", "/"]
COPY ["model.h5", "/"]
COPY ["run_server.sh", "/"]

RUN chmod +x /run_server.sh

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install tensorflow && \
    pip3 install h5py && \
    pip3 install flask && \
    pip3 install gensim


EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/run_server.sh"]
CMD ["master"]
```

And it is the run_server.sh that I use:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
export LANG=C.UTF-8
python3 -u /main.py
```

Then you have to follow the next steps:

```
Generation Docker Image: docker build . -t [IMAGE]

Tag Local Docker Image: docker tag [IMAGE] eu.gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]

Push Docker Image: docker push eu.gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]

Deploy App: gcloud app deploy --image-url=eu.gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]
```

And it is working nice now :)

Answer (score 0):

The error you’re experiencing seems to be pointing out that the **GAE instance** you’re using is running **out of memory**.

As an option, you might want to try changing the [**class**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes) of the instance to the one that has a higher memory limit. However, keep in mind that it will also affect the [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#standard_instance_pricing).